# cannot access the data of the first API in second API function

Tags: javascript

```
 <script>
        /* 1st API*/
        $.getJSON("http://cricapi.com/api/matches/?apikey=6aP8B4MImxSNxI6fevBmC2ZshO42",function(data){
         var len = data.matches.length;
         for(i=0;i<len;i++){

              id = data.matches[i].unique_id;
              ms = data.matches[i].matchStarted;
              x = data.matches[i].date;
              team_1 = data.matches[i]['team-1']
               /* 2nd  API*/
             $.getJSON("https://cricapi.com/api/cricketScore/?apikey=6aP8B4MImxSNxI6fevBmC2ZshO42&unique_id="+id,function(data1){
                    console.log(team_1);

                              });
                 }
  });
```

why i cannot get the **team_1** of each match in second `getJSON()`. It is giving the output of same team name multiple times please help me to get the team names of each match. Appreciate any help!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1):

This "bug" is caused by [hoisting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp).

Index *i* is stored as *var*, and it isn't in local for loop scope, so, when the index has gained its final value, the same value is used.

You can use *let* keyword:

```
for(let i=0;i<len;i++){ ..
```

so the variable will be loop scoped

Also Check out  this [link](https://dev.to/emnudge/how-for-loops-really-work-4lhj)

Answer (score -2):

```
function getScore(id, callback) {
    $.getJSON("https://cricapi.com/api/cricketScore/?apikey=6aP8B4MImxSNxI6fevBmC2ZshO42&unique_id="+id, function(data1) {
        callback(data1);
    });
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://cricapi.com/api/matches/?apikey=6aP8B4MImxSNxI6fevBmC2ZshO42",function(data){
        var len = data.matches.length;
        for(i=0;i<len;i++){
            id = data.matches[i].unique_id;
            ms = data.matches[i].matchStarted;
            x = data.matches[i].date;
            team_1 = data.matches[i]['team-1']
            /* 2nd  API*/
            getScore(id, function(data1) {
                console.log(data1);
            });
        }
    });
});
```